# Maximum Eigenvalue of a Symmetric Matrix!!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $M=A-B$ be a symmetric matrix of order n.

I know $\lambda_{max}=\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^tMx}{x^t x}$.  Where $ x\in R^n$.

Can I write it like $\lambda_{max}=\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^tAx}{x^t x}-\inf_{y\neq 0} \frac{y^tBy}{y^t y}$?

Note that my confusion is about vectors $x$ and $y$. Should they remain same or can they be different?

Comment: It must be same ..for example $I$ = $[1,0;0,2] - [0,0;0,1]$. $\lmabda_{max}$ for identity matrix is $1$ but it is not equal to the difference between maximum eigenvalue of first matrix and minimum eigenvalue of second matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If we simply derive the computation you suggest we get:
\begin{align*}
\lambda_\max (M) &= \sup_{x\neq0} \frac{x^\top M x}{x^\top x}\\
&= \sup_{x\neq0} \frac{x^\top (A-B) x}{x^\top x}\\
&= \sup_{x\neq0} \left( \frac{x^\top A x}{x^\top x} - \frac{x^\top B x}{x^\top x} \right)
\end{align*}
But you cannot separate the $\sup$. Always try to think of simple examples in $\mathbb{R}$, such as

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) + g(x) \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) + \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} g(y)$$
this holds because you basically have "more freedom" on the right-hand side.